# FastAPI: How to show multiple request examples in the docs and keep the default one

Tags: python, fastapi

I would like to show different example for a request in the FastAPI docs.
As described here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example

This code creates two examples ("Denmark, Sweden") but when I run it, the auto
generated full example is no longer available.

How can I keep the default example at the top of the example list without having to manually recreate it?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn


class HelloWorld(BaseModel):
    hello: str
    world: str = "World"

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
def post_root(
    hwr: HelloWorld = Body(
        ...,
        examples={
         
            # add "default example" here  
            "denmark": {"summary": "A Denmark example", "value": {"hello": "denmark"}},
            "sweden": {"summary": "A Sweden example", "value": {"hello": "sweden"}},
        }

    )
):
    return {"Hello": "World"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5085)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a "default" entry with no "value" adds the default to the list of examples.

```
    examples={
        # add "default example" here  
        "default": {"summary": "Default example"},

        "denmark": {"summary": "A Denmark example", "value": {"hello": "denmark"}},
        "sweden": {"summary": "A Sweden example", "value": {"hello": "sweden"}},
    }
```

Note: If you want to do the same with responses, this [Medium article](https://archive.ph/OmDqt) explains how to do it.